# WP8 Error When Trying to Re-Add Push-Pins on Zoom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I try to zoom in (Button_Click_1 event) I'm getting an error as I try to add images/layers back to a map.

I should note: I've simplified the code substantially so that it would be easier to pick out the error (that I can't seem to figure out).
 Each zoom level has a different set of images which are attached to it in case you're wondering why I need to continually clear the layers/images.

Each of the Images/Layers/Overlays is defined globally (so that I can use them in several methods

```
 Image img1 = new Image();
     Image img2 = new Image();
     MapLayer lyr1 = new MapLayer();
     MapLayer lyr2 = new MapLayer();
     MapOverlay ovrly1 = new MapOverlay();
     MapOverlay ovrly2 = new MapOverlay();
```

Each of these is initialized when the page loads in a separate method:

```
     private void initializeImages()
     {
         ovrly1.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.33783000, -0.45215600);
         img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/push-pin.png", UriKind.Relative));
         ovrly1.Content = img1;
         ovrly1.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
         img1.Opacity = 0.8;
         img1.Height = 30;
         img1.Width = 30;
         img1.Tap += img1_Tap;
         ovrly2.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.35783000, -0.45425600);
         img2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/push-pin.png", UriKind.Relative));
         ovrly2.Content = img2;
         ovrly2.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
         img2.Opacity = 0.8;
         img2.Height = 30;
         img2.Width = 30;
         img2.Tap += img2_Tap;
     }
```

When I try to zoom on the Button_Click the first time it works fine. But any other time I try to zoom I get an error:

```
     private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         map1.ZoomLevel += 1;
         map1.Layers.Clear();

         lyr1.Add(ovrly1);  // ERROR OCCURS HERE
         map1.Layers.Add(lyr1);

         lyr2.Add(ovrly2);
         map1.Layers.Add(lyr2);
     }
```

This error disappears when I declare all of the images/overlays/layers 'locally' inside the Button_Click event. But I can't do that, otherwise I won't be able to access the Images outside of the method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are adding many overlays on exactly same position.

Additionaly, in the Button Click event you clear the Layers element of the map, but you don't do the same with each layer, adding new elements to to the layer which already have one, each time. Since you add the elements in the same position, you get the error.

Following code should work if both elements have different `GeoCoordinate` values:

```
    private void Botoia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        map1.ZoomLevel += 1;
        map1.Layers.Clear();

        lyr1.Clear();
        lyr2.Clear();

        lyr1.Add(ovrly1);
        map1.Layers.Add(lyr1);

        lyr2.Add(ovrly2);
        map1.Layers.Add(lyr2);
    }
```